# How to intercept each request of WebBrowser and forward to a webproxy?

Tags: c#, browser

I'm working on a WinForm WebBrowser and I want to forward each request to my web proxy and receive the response from the web proxy, the web proxy will forward the response directly to user, include headers and content.

I need change the URL and postdata for each request.

About the page navigate, I have implement the method in AxWebBrowser_beforeNavigate2 , but it is no use for images, js, css etc.

And now, perhaps using Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol (APP) and override IInternetSession::RegisterNameSpace is required, but I have no experience on it.

The Development Envrionment: .Net 2.0 , VS2008

Would someone give me some sample code for it ?  thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? That's important. The fact that you're using Visual Studio 2008 is not important, as you will only be using that to write the program, and it can target different versions of .NET.

Comment: I'm using .Net 2.0 now, thank you.

Comment: I found a good example(echo protocol and aspx protocol) from: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspxProtocol.aspx , it is permanent protocol, but I need a temperary protocol.

Answer (score 0):

How about UrlMkSetSessionOption with INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY?

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use a webproxy, not a standard proxy, so I need a temperory Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol to handle it. But I have not found a temperory example for it yet.